# Building a Web App using Drupal

Tags: installation-profiles

I'm looking at building a Web Application on the Drupal framework. Does anyone know of an existing drupal profile installation that has this viewpoint?

For example, I've been building features for Open Atrium and I'm familiar with some of the concepts and modules this contains. However, Open Atrium does not really satisfy the concept of clients having a profile and creating projects with subscriptions.

So in essence, I'm looking for a package similar to Open Atrium, but satisfies a web application development. Think of it more as building web tools like Basecamp or Freebooks, but using a base platform to get there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating your own install profile doesn't need to be a big project in itself, especially for Drupal 7, that has simplified making install profiles. Features also helps a lot, making it easy to save settings, content types, views etc in a module.

All you really need to do in the install profile is to

- Enable modules
- Save settings
- Enable blocks (maybe)
- Create content (maybe)

I suggest that you build your own install profile that fits your needs, instead of trying to find one. You could start out with how it's done in Open Atrium, and just edit it to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, building web apps with drupal is not really a good idea, but it depends upon the size of the application that you will be seeing in the end.

If you can clarify what kind of web application we might be talking about then I can give a more suitable answer.

Comment: I think I am fairly clear in my question. In essence, the applications could vary entirely. But essential, I'm looking for a base framework (similar to a set of og, spaces, and features), but with the viewpoint of projects, not really groups. Something that one could use to build apps like basecamp, or an entirely new idea of projects and features.

Comment: Well in my experience creating web apps of large scale with drupal is very difficult. Though with Drupal 7 having unit testing built right into it has some advantages of testing the new modules you develop easily, but going for a framework say php framework or maybe ruby on rails is the best way to develop web apps. Using rails the web apps I have developed, we are able to test our projects continuously, rapidly develop new features and deploying new versions is real fun. These things are not available with drupal. Also performance tweaking in custom apps is real easy, fun and more effective.

Comment: Intersting input! I am finding that this is a valid point. What alternative PHP frameworks would you suggest that already have some level of modules in place, in particular, a framework that supports similar concepts to drupal in menus and permissions. I've worked extensively with Cakephp in the past, but found that I had to build much of the needed basic functionality from scratch.